# MapInfo workspace problem

Tags: mapinfo, workspace

I have opened a workspace with a file on a CD and now it will only open when the CD is in the CD drive - I can't find a way around it

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit the file path in the workspace using a text editor. After it says Open Table you will need to set the path to the local files